# How to access query parameters from route in Ember 1.7

Tags: ember.js

In 1.7 Ember should support Query Parameters. I have no problems using them in controller but I'd like to access them in Route, ideally in beforeModel hook but model hook would work as well.

The [API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_beforeModel) mention a `queryParam` parameter for the beforeModel hook but if I try to use it, it is always undefined.

The [Query Parameters guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/) seems to suggest that the query parameters should be accessible as a part of the first parameter to the model hook. But that is also undefined. See the code below for examples.

Is there a way to access the query parameters from Route?

Thank you for your help.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   beforeModel: function(transition, queryParams){
       console.log(queryParams.test); //undefined at /?test=123
   },
   model: function(params){
       console.log(params.test); //undefined at /?test=123
   }
});
```

Comment: You should be able to pull it off of the `params` object in the model hook. see: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/necid/1/edit?html,js,console,output Are you setting `test` as a queryParam in the controller?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. It never occurred to me that Controller could affect Route. I thought that the setting was only for accessing queryParams directly in the Controller.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pretty sure it's a bug, but you can access them in the meantime via the transition object:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   beforeModel: function(transition){
       console.log(transition.queryParams.test);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work and it's cleaner to do this in beforeModel hook. It's strange that even in 1.8.1 it still hasn't been fixed. I'm not sure if it's a bug or just an unclear documentation.

Comment: @typeoneerror: Your solution only works if the locationType is auto. Do you know how to grab query params if the location type is hash

Answer (score 8):

By specifying the query params in the controller, `params` will contain them automatically

```js
ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['test'],
  test: null
});
```

Comment: How can access them? `console.log(this.get('test'))` is throwing me an undefined. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly...same issue ?

Comment: In the route you can get the value of `test` using `this.controller.get('test')`

Comment: You can get the value in route as
beforeModel(params){
     console.log(params.queryParams.test);
}

Answer (score 7):

In the latest version of ember (2.12 at the time of writing this answer), queryParams can be accessed in the model hook as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        test: ''
    },
    model(params) {
        console.log(params.test);
    },
});
```

Observe that now both dynamic segment and `queryParams` are accessible via the `params` object. Since `params` is not available in the `beforeModel` hook, this solution works on when you have to access the `queryParams` in the `model` hook.

Answer (score 5):

In latest ember version you can get the value in Route as

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel(params){ 
      console.log(params.queryParams.test); //if the parameter contains test as the key
  }
});
```

This works only if the locationType is auto in your environment.js file.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to access in didTransition action,

```
didTransition: (queryParams) ->
  console.log(@get('queryParams'))
```