# Why doesn't my model hook receive no param?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Disclaimer: major newbie warning!

I've successfully set up a Rails backend/Ember front-end project following [this](https://devmynd.com/blog/2014-7-rails-ember-js-with-the-ember-cli-redux-part-2-the-front-end-with-ember-and-the-ember-cli) tutorial.

My router is

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('contacts', function() {
    this.resource('contact', { path: '/:contact_id' });
  });
});

export default Router;
```

Now I want to set up the possibility for finding only certain contacts based on the contact's lastName, so I followed the [official docs for specifying query params](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/).

I've modified my `app/routes/contacts/index.js` route so that it now looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    lastName: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findQuery('contact', params);
  }
});
```

and `app/controllers/contacts.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  queryParams: ['lastName'],
  lastName: null,

});
```

Unfortunately, `params` isn't filled, even when I specify a query param in the browser. More precisely, the `params` object looks like this:

[image]

which doesn't seem to contain anything interesting to me.

Yet, the query params information *is* somehow propagated to the view, so I feel slightly baffled. How can I have `params` be filled for the model hook in my route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though [this might be a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26706095/182048). A simple work around is accessing the query params through the optional transition param:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    lastName: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  model: function(params, transition) {
    return this.store.findQuery('contact', transition.queryParams);
  }
});
```