# How to access params in the afterModel hook

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I was using an RSVP.hash in my `model` hook. But I needed my route to load dynamic data based on the url (which contains a dynamic segment). i.e. `this.route('foo', {path: ':id'})`.

So I decided to move some stuff out, to the `afterModel` hook instead.

However, I needed to execute the store with `params` (for pagination):

```
model(params) {
  this.set('params', params);
  return this.store.findRecord('foo', params.foo_id);
},

afterModel: function(model) {
  console.log(this.get('params')); // logs the right params
  let params = this.get('params');

  // This store query needs access to params
  this.store.query('bar', { filter: { 'foo-id': model.get('id') }, page: { number: (params.page ? params.page : 1) } }).then(bars => {
    this.controller.set('bars', bars);
  });
}

setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);

  this.set('bars', bars);
}
```

So far I have this, which works:

```
model(params) {
  this.set('params', params);
  ...
},

afterModel: function(model) {
  console.log(this.get('params')); // logs the right params
  ...
}
```

But is this the only way to access `params` in the `afterModel` hook?

Is this approach sane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `afterModel` hook provides a second argument named `transition`. You can get the params from it using a path like this: `transition.params.{route-name}.{param-name}`, so considering your example:

```
//let's say this is BazRoute and BazController:

model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('foo', params.foo_id);
},

afterModel: function(model, transition) {
  const params = transition.params.baz;
  console.log(params); // logs the right params

  // This store query needs access to params
  this.store.query('bar', { filter: { 'foo-id': model.get('id') }, page: { number: (params.page ? params.page : 1) } }).then(bars => {
    this.controller.set('bars', bars);
  });
}
```

Comment: But my model is now a `RSVP.hash`, which takes us back to the issue in the first place. No? More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route

Comment: @ChristianFazzini I've rewritten my answer :)

Comment: Oh nice! Didnt know that! For the curious. If route name has two or more words. Then something like `transition.params['foo-bar']` will suffice. I wonder why there isnt much mention about this on the net (let alone, not documented in the docs)

Comment: This q&a is about dynamic segments. In case anyone else was looking for QUERY params, those are in `transition.queryParams`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941837/how-to-access-query-parameters-from-route-in-ember-1-7

Comment: As of ember 3.7 accessing the params on the transition will throw a deprecation warning. Using @Epirocks answer works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `this.paramsFor(this.routeName)` function to get a plain object with the params in.